# How to do ps pipelines with linux?

Tags: bash, pipeline, ps

I tried pipelines like

```
ps -A | grep "smthn" | kill -4 (smthn's PID)
```

So how can i grab multiple processes PID's from grep output?
Like `ps -A | grep "smthn", "smthn1", "smthn2" | kill -4 (smthn's PID)`

Comment: Can you find all process with a single grep? or you will need more greps to find all? e.g all the taks starts with `smt..` or one starts with `smth` the other with `thm` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `kill` reads from `stdin`, it only takes pids as arguments. So use `kill $(...)` instead, where the code to find the pids replaces the dots in the `$(...)` part.

To find the pids:

```sh
ps -A | grep smthn | grep -v grep | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Here the first `grep` looks for smthn, the second grep filters out the `grep` command that is looking for smthn and is still running at this time. Then [`cut`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) picks just the first field of the output, which is the pid.

Put together:

```sh
kill -4 $(ps -A | grep smthn | grep -v grep | cut -d " " -f 1)
```

If you have [`pgrep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) and [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) and the process is always named the same (always smthn, not smthn1, smthn2, and so on), you can simplify this a lot. `pgrep` just returns the pid, so you don't need to work with `grep -v` and `cut`:

```sh
kill -4 $(pgrep smthn)
```

`pkill` just sends the signal to whatever process executable you specify:

```sh
pkill -4 smthn
```